# swiftUi : 2 Pickers on one screen - app crash with "Index out of range"

Tags: xcode, swiftui, picker

When I try to put 2 pikers with a different number of rows on-screen with different observers.
if I select in one number of the row that not exists in the second,
when I move to the second picker app crash with this message: 
"Fatal error: Index out of range"

```
public enum kTrackType {
    case audio
    case text
}

class kTrack: NSObject, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
    public var trakcId: String
    public var title: String
    public var type: kTrackType

    public init(id: String, title: String, type: kTrackType) {

        self.trakcId = id
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

and this is the main struct:

```
struct SelectedAudioAndSubtileView: View {

let geometry: GeometryProxy

@State var subtitlesList = [kTrack(id: "t0", title: "None", type: kTrackType.text),
                            kTrack(id: "t1", title: "En", type: kTrackType.text),
                            kTrack(id: "t2", title: "Rus", type: kTrackType.text),
                            kTrack(id: "t3", title: "Spn", type: kTrackType.text)]

@State var multiAudioList =  [kTrack(id: "s0", title: "En", type: kTrackType.audio),
                              kTrack(id: "s1", title: "Rus", type: kTrackType.audio)]

@Binding var showSubtitlesPicker: Bool

@State private var selectedAudioPicker: Int = 0

@State private var selectedSubtitlePicker: Int = 0

@State private var selectedType = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Picker(selection: $selectedType, label: EmptyView()) {
            Text("Audio").tag(0)
            Text("Subtitle").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

        Text(self.selectedType == 0 ? "Select Audio" : "Select Subtitle")
        Divider()

        if selectedType == 0 {
            Picker(selection: self.$selectedAudioPicker, label: Text("")) {

                ForEach(self.multiAudioList, id: \.id){ name in
                    Text(name.title)
                }
            }
        } else {
           Picker(selection: self.$selectedSubtitlePicker, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(self.subtitlesList, id: \.id){ name in
                    Text(name.title)
                }
            }
        }
        Divider()
    }
    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1)))
    .offset(y: geometry.size.height - 330)
}
```

After recheck, the crash happened also if you have same rows in 2 pickers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the situation :

a) the `selectedValue` should match the tag value, therefore in `ForEach`, it's better to use `index` not the `id` so that you can add tag for each items.

b) the `ForEach` structure is a complex one and usually to be reused for performance. So in order to force it refresh, `id()` modifier can be added to extra `ForEach` structures. There must be one `ForEach` without `id` which provides the real underlying data layer.

```
if selectedType == 0 {
    Picker (selection: self.$selectedAudioPicker, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0..<self.multiAudioList.count){ index in
            Text(self.multiAudioList[index].title).tag(index)
        }
    }

} else if  selectedType == 1 {
    Picker(selection: self.$selectedSubtitlePicker, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0..<self.subtitlesList.count){ index in
            Text(self.subtitlesList[index].title).tag(index)
        }.id(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, but when I go back to the last page, if I close Picker app crash with: "precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 74"
Any idea?

Comment: How do you close an app?